# nginx reverse to ssl backend

Tags: nginx, ssl

i get crt file from a partner, i want to let nginx do ssl connection so i follow this note : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/ i don't have client pem file and client key file. How can i generate this files with crt to fill this directives:

```
location /upstream { proxy_pass https://backend.example.com;   proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/client.pem;
```

proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/client.key;
}

actually my location :

```
    location /api {

    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.log upstream_logging ;
    
   proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/partner.crt;
   
  # proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/client.key;
  # proxy_ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/client.pem;
   proxy_ssl_verify       off;
   proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
   proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
   proxy_ssl_server_name on;
   #proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 ;


    
    proxy_pass https://api$uri$is_args$args;

}
```

with this setting i get this error:
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream

how to get client.key? is this generated from crt file?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a client key.
Error `SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protoco` probably indicates that the protocol was not chosen correctly in `proxy_ssl_protocols`

Official documentation [nginx.org proxy_ssl_protocols](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_protocols)

Comment: i try to give (proxy_ssl_protocols) any possible value and restart nginx each time. Same error. i use portecle java program to examine .crt file, he display version=3.